# How to set focus to top frame within an iframe crossdomain.

Tags: javascript, html, cross-domain, same-origin-policy

I have an iframe in my web-page. So when Esc is pressed inside the iframe I need to set focus the top frame of document. The iframe is from an different domain. [image]

Here Frame-B URL will be some abc.com and frame-A will be from xyz.com

So when an event is fired in Frame-B I need to focus Frame-A.

I can bind any number of events in Frame-A and Frame-B.

I have found a old way like this "An iframe in an iframe in an iframe". which am not interested in.

Any Idea how this can be done?

Answer (score 4):

If you have some control over the outer frame (let's say it's your site, but still a different one than B), then there's a number of solutions to your problem. **If you don't have any control over the outer frame**, (because it is google.com for example) **then there's nothing you can do**. The browsers are designed to prevent it. See Jonas answer.

So what about if you can control the outer page? Any of the following would work:

- Use [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage). All you have to do is adding an very generic event listener in Frame-A. It's available in "all" browsers except IE7 and below.
- Use a server as a middleman. Send a request from Frame-B to your server and let Frame-A access it from there. If you don't want to poll, you could use web sockets in Frame-A (or rather a good web socket lib, that fallbacks on other technologies if web sockets are not present).
- Use the fragment identifier hack. You can read about that (and several other techniques) here: http://softwareas.com/cross-domain-communication-with-iframes